# CSS Substring display none

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in CSS (only) to `hide` some text of a string?
I know there these attribute-selectores like:

```html
[att^=val] – the “begins with” selector
```

But for instance, having this:

```html
<div class="some_random_text">
    This is a default text
</div>
```

I want to (display: none) only a certain substring - in thise case "default". I know how to do it with JS, but I'm looking for a CSS-solution only (if there is any).

Even though I guess it isn't possible to manipulate the DOM **via CSS**, which would be neccessary to have something like:

```html
this is a <span class="hideThis">default</span> text
```

> why would you need this and where does it occur?

For instance in a CMS (in my case OXID). You can add a title to a specific payment-method. Here I have

- paypal
- paypal (provider1)
- paypal (another dude)

I want to have only **PayPal** visible in the frontend. The other PayPal-Paymenttypes have to remain however. Naming them all **PayPal** just leads to confusion.

there is the `content`-property. Is it somehow managable with that?

Again, no JS :-)

Comment: Most likely not possible with only CSS

Comment: `this is a <span class="hideThis">default</span> text`

i dont get why this isnt a correct work around ? add css rules on this class that display:none and off you go

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor see updated question. Maybe that clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - no, it's not possible using only CSS.

You can;

- Edit the HTML as you suggested

> this is a <.span class="hideThis">default<.span > text

- Use JS to alter the elements innerHTML value
- Use a pre-processing language (like PHP or ASP, whatever you are able to use) to reduce the string to a substring.

Sorry if that's not the answer you wanted, but those are your options.

Comment: naw, that's totally fine. These are the options I thought of as well. Just wanted to play it safe :)

Comment: Fair play - worth a check!

Answer (score 1):

It it not possible. The only thing that can actually modify the inside text is the `content` property. Assuming something changes in your dom, you can have rules like:

```
.some_random_text:after {
  content: "This is a text";
}

other_select .some_random_text:after {
    content: "This is a default text";
}
```

But sincerely, I don't get the point, as JS and consors are made for that.

Comment: Indeed - this would be a poor way for managing your content. And as Shitsu says, the alternatives are much better and easy to implement...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, here's the documentation on selectors: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors